# Mismatched types with `.enumerate()`: expected type `u8`, found reference `&_`

Tags: types, rust, pattern-matching, type-inference, type-mismatch

The following snippet doesn't compile

```rust
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let indices_of_odd_numbers = (1..100)
        .map(|_| rng.gen::<u8>())
        .enumerate()
        .filter(|(_, &x)| x % 2 == 1)
        .map(|(i, _)| i)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("{:?}", &indices_of_odd_numbers);
}
```

with an error message of

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:22
  |
9 |         .filter(|(_, &x)| x % 2 == 1)
  |                      ^^- expected due to this
  |                      |
  |                      expected `u8`, found reference
  |                      help: you can probably remove the explicit borrow: `x`
  |
  = note:   expected type `u8`
          found reference `&_`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

However, it compiles smoothly when I replace `.filter(|(_, &x)| x % 2 == 1)` with `.filter(|(_, x)| *x % 2 == 1)`. Moreover, once I get rid of `.enumerate()`, the following snippet which uses pattern matching to implictly deference `x` to `u8` also compiles

```rust
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let odd_numbers = (1..100)
        .map(|_| rng.gen::<u8>())
        .filter(|&x| x % 2 == 1)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("{:?}", &odd_numbers);
}
```

I cannot understand why pattern matching doesn't work with `.enumerate()`. Why can't the compiler infer that `x` should be a `u8` and dereference it in the first snippet?

Comment: The rand generator doesn't produce references but u8. And the dereference of the tuple is automatic. There's no reason for the &, nor for the * (even in the second snippet).

Comment: @Stargateur Okay, I see... but why does `.filter(|(_, x)| *x % 2 == 1)` work? How does patterning matching apply something with type `&(usize, u8)` to `(_, x)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate()` create a tuple, on your case a `(usize, u8)`, `filter()` send the `Item` of the `Iterator` by reference, so `&(usize, u8)` not a `(&usize, &u8)`. So `|(_, &x)|` don't make sense cause for the compiler you try to dereference a `u8`. What you could do is `|&(_, x)|` but again the compiler is smart enough to suggest to simply remove `&` of `&x` and your original would compile.

`.filter(|(_, x)| *x % 2 == 1)` is more complicated, `|(_, x)|` could be write `|(_, ref x)|` the inverse of `&x` this mean take `x` as a reference. So here the compiler auto add `ref` keyword and you simply dereference `x` then. It's more explicit but not needed.

More info on [RFC 2005](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md) and [binding modes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html?highlight=auto%20ref#binding-modes)

Comment: Where can I read more about Rust’s pattern matching rules? It’s a little mind blowing that Rust can implicitly convert `|(_, x)|` to `|&(_, x)|` before performing pattern matching. I’m happy to work with such a smart compiler, but smartness also makes it harder to understand its behavior.

Comment: @nalzok *It’s a little mind blowing that Rust can implicitly convert...* - This specific feature is called [match ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md) and was even a bit controversial. It was decided to be a net win, though, because it made pattern-matching options much less of a PITA, particularly to beginners.

Comment: @nalzok generally you don't have too, on your case the compiler tell you what was the correct code, just write code simply and let compiler to the job, I never write `ref` anymore since 3 years. I added a link